# use global SLA in byon but have exception "no management space located".

Tags: cloudify

[byon with phycal machine, SLA is global, how to ensure that the applications are not be installed on the same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551029/byon-with-phycal-machine-sla-is-global-how-to-ensure-that-the-applications-are)

I set this SLA in jetty-service.groovy 
isolationSLA { 
    global 
        { instanceCpuCores 0 instanceMemoryMB 256 useManagement false } 
    } But when I deploy an application with 2 instance, then two instance be install in same machine, at last, the result is one instance start successful, but another start failed, the failed one get an exception: "no management space located". I find this exception in org.cloudifysource.utilitydomain.context.kvstore.AttributesFacadeImpl.getManagem‌​entSpace() the exception in the pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MVF9.png
how can i do? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be an apparent reason for this to happen.
Most likely this is due to heavy load on the machine, check you CPU and memory readings while you deploy.

It may be just a matter of using a larger machine..

Hope this helps.